# Color normalization based on known objects

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I was unable to find literature on this.

The question is that given some photograph with a well known object within it - say something that was printed for this purpose, how well does the approach work to use that object to infer lighting conditions as a method of color profile calibration.

For instance, say we print out the peace flag rainbow and then take a photo of it in various lighting conditions with a consumer-grade flagship smartphone camera (say, iphone 6, nexus 6) the underlying question is whether using known references within the image is a potentially good technique in calibrating the colors throughout the image

There's of course a number of issues regarding variance of lighting conditions in different regions of the photograph along with what wavelengths the device is capable from differentiating in even the best circumstances --- but let's set them aside.

Has anyone worked with this technique or seen literature regarding it, and if so, can you point me in the direction of some findings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a standard technique, however one simple way to calibrate your color channels would be to learn a regression model (for each pixel) between the colors that are present in the region and their actual colors. If you have some shots of known images, you should have sufficient data to learn the transformation model using a neural network (or a simpler model like linear regression if you like, but a NN would be able to capture multi-modal mappings). You can even do a patch based regression using a NN on small patches (say 8x8, or 16x16) if you need to learn some spatial dependencies between intensities.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but you should pay attention to the way your known object reacts to light. Ideally it should be non-glossy, have identical colours when pictured from an angle, be totally non-transparent, and reflect all wavelengths outside the visible spectrum to which your sensor is sensitive (IR, UV, no filter is perfect) **uniformly across all different coloured regions**. Emphasis added because this last one is very important and very hard to get right.

However, the main issue you have with a coloured known object is: What are the actual colours of the different regions in RGB(*)? So in this way you can determine the effect of different lighting conditions between each other, but never relative to some ground truth.

The solution: use a uniformly white, non-reflective, intransparant surface: A sufficiently thick sheet of white paper should do just fine. Take a non-overexposed photograph of the sheet in your scene, and you know:

1. R, G and B should be close to equal
2. R, G and B should be nearly 255.

From those two facts and the R, G and B values you actually get from the sheet you can determine any shift in colour and brightness in your scene. Assume that black is still black (usually a reasonable assumption) and use linear interpolation to determine the shift experienced by pixels coloured somewhere between 0 and 255 on any of the axed.

(*) or other colourspace of your choice.